# Видеофайлы MTS (m2ts) открыть, Федора 27

Tags: linux, видео

После обновления с 25 до 27 Федоры перестали открываться файлы MTS с камеры. (Хотя и до этого они открывались далеко не всем)
Даже smplayer не хочет. Одни проигрыватели ничего вообще ни пишут, только звук, другие пишут, что нужен кодек H.264 и предлагают установить. Затем ошибка — кодек уже установлен.

Конвертировать — НЕ ВАРИАНТ. Видео очень много.

Большая вероятность, что дальше придется пользоваться программами для создания субтитров, а они тоже не хотят открывать видео. Так что искать плеер не целостное решение проблемы. Нужно заставить систему работать: или установить нужные кодеки (хотя я не понимаю уже какие) или настроить эти.

Comment: Если ffmpeg не проигрывает, то надо будет искать кодеки.

Comment: Не проигрывает. Вы имели в виду не открывает? ffmpeg это же не проигрыватель, а перекодировщик. Или я что-то пропустил.
ffmpeg  выводит информацию о потоке 

Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25.25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
At least one output file must be specified

Comment: *ffmpeg* — и перекодировщик, и проигрыватель. `ffplay`, если мне память не изменяет, команда запуска проигрывателя. А кодек у вас действительно h264, вот с ним что-то не так (либо с потоком, если он врёт о реальном кодеке).

Comment: Проигрывает, но тормоза жуткие. Видео рывками.